# Golang , TLS forward proxy server (tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake)

Tags: golang, proxy, tls

я новичок в GO, и для обучения я хотел создать прокси-сервер прямого доступа, поддерживающий HTTPS. Я столкнулся с проблемой, которую не могу решить, даже не нашел решения на github и stackoverflow

когда я установил этот прокси в ОС (Windows) и попытался сделать запрос из браузера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

по запросу  https://localhost:8888 (локалхост задекларирован в корневом хранилище сертификатов , сертификаты являются самовыписаными) :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

log:
http: TLS handshake error from [::1]:49972:tls:first record does not look like a TLS handshake
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

code :

https://github.com/AlexDespod/golang/blob/26211aee18d5e720d0b5f1b8b556c254e880be38/main/main.go

спасибо заранtе)

Comment: будет прекрасно, если вы вместо картинки вставите текст логов.

Comment: Примеров в Интернете достаточно - [1](https://golangcode.com/basic-https-server-with-certificate/), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46992030/how-to-set-up-https-on-golang-web-server), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63588254/how-to-set-up-an-https-server-with-a-self-signed-certificate-in-golang)